# can not clone a repository

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I want to clone a repository to local, but I got the following error

```
$ git clone git://github.com/xxx/xxx.git                                                                                                           
Cloning into 'xxx'...
remote: Counting objects: 320, done.
remote: Total 320 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 320
Receiving objects: 100% (320/320), 68.94 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (134/134), done.
fatal: did not receive expected object a5231ceb78c135e9230936e0469d712dbb7a7a3c
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Attention, this error is not the same error as

```
index-pack failed
```

I have tried this solution
https://newbedev.com/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed

but that is not right solution to solve this problem

any ideas?

Comment: Works fine for me, though note that I get very different counts than you show (`remote: Enumerating objects: 799, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (73/73), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (57/57), done.
remote: Total 799 (delta 24), reused 40 (delta 11), pack-reused 726`). There is no `a5231ceb78c135e9230936e0469d712dbb7a7a3c` object though. Are you expecting one, e.g., via a submodule gitlink?

Comment: Hi I mean the other repository

Comment: There appears to be no `git://github.com/xxx/xxx.git`.